# Alphabetic order of Charts in r

Tags: r, charts

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(21)
a<-sapply(1:4, function(x) sample(0:50, 4, replace=T))
colnames(a)<-c("A","B","C","D")
n <- 4
best <- vector("character",n)
sbest <- vector("character",n)
for (i in 1:4){
  best[i]=LETTERS[which(a[i,]==max(a[i,]))]
  sbest[i]=LETTERS[which(a[i,]==sort(a[i,],partial=n-1)[n-1])]
}
BestO<-paste(best, sbest, sep=",")
data<-cbind(a,BestO)

       A    B    C    D   BestO     WHAT I WANT
[1,] "40" "48" "50" "2"  "C,B"        "B,C"
[2,] "12" "46" "43" "31" "B,C"        "B,C"
[3,] "35" "5"  "34" "8"  "A,C"        "A,C"
[4,] "9"  "8"  "47" "1"  "C,A"        "A,C"
```

In other words, I want the letters in **each** row to be in alphabetical order. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. `buttons` object is missing.

Comment: Also  LETTERS  is not defined.

Comment: @tatxif `LETTERS` is a built-in R object. A vector of length 26 consisting of the capital latin characters, informally known as the "ABCs."

Comment: @lmo Good to know! Live and learn :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the sorting and then find the letters, something like that

```
 set.seed(21)
 a<-sapply(1:4, function(x) sample(0:50, 4, replace=T))
 colnames(a)<-c("A","B","C","D")

 best <- vector("numeric",n)
 sbest <- vector("numeric",n)
 BestO <- NULL
 n <- 4
 for (i in 1:4){
   best[i]=which(a[i,]==max(a[i,]))
   sbest[i]=which(a[i,]==sort(a[i,],partial=n-1)[n-1])
   cur <- t(letters[sort(c(best[i],sbest[i]))])
   BestO[i] <-  paste(cur[1],cur[2],sep=",")
 }

 data <- cbind(a,BestO)
```

Comment: @YefR thanks! arghhh autocorrection.. it was the only line I didn't paste from my R script!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but it works. We need to sort arrays of characters instead of a joined character. The following gets the character data into arrays then sorts it and joins the character back together to get the desired output:

```
    best_list <- strsplit(data[, 5], ",")
    best_mat <- sapply(best_list, sort)
    t_best_mat <- t(best_mat)
    sorted_best <- paste(t_best_mat[, 1], t_best_mat[, 2], sep = ",")
```